# Using CP prove the truth of a tautology

Tags: logic

Having trouble figuring out this tautology using CP and the rules of infrence

[P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)] ≡ [Q ⊃ (P ⊃ R)]

Comment: CP means? Not sure I've seen that term before.

Comment: Conditional Proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For A) :

> $[P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)] \supset [Q ⊃ (P ⊃ R)]$

1) $[P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)]$ --- assumed for [Conditional Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)

2) $Q$ --- assumed [a] for *CP*

3) $P$ --- assumed [b] for *CP*

4) $(Q ⊃ R)$ --- from 1) and 3) by [Modus Ponens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference) or *Conditional Elimination*

5) $R$ --- from 4) and 2) by *MP*

6) $(P ⊃ R)$ --- from 3) and 5) by *CP*, discharging assumption [b]

7) $[Q ⊃ (P ⊃ R)]$ --- from 2) and 6) by *CP*, discharging assumption [a]

> 8) $[P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)] \supset [Q ⊃ (P ⊃ R)]$ --- from 1) and 7) by *CP*

---

The same for B) :

> $[Q ⊃ (P ⊃ R)] \supset [P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)]$

---

From A) and b) we conclude with :

> > $[P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)] \equiv [Q ⊃ (P ⊃ R)]$

by [Biconditional introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference).

Comment: The proof of B) can get constructed by substituting Q with P, and P with Q throughout the proof of A).